# mle2 (bbmle) parameter estimates on boundary, NaNs produced in object@vcov

Tags: r, mle

I'm trying to run a MLE for an infectious disease compartmental transmission model (SEIR, in my case SSEIR) with the mle2 command, trying to fit a curve of predicted number of weekly deaths to that of observed weekly deaths similar to this:
[plot of predicted vs observed weekly deaths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Gxb.png).
However, the parameter estimates seem to always be on the (sensible) boundaries I provide and SEs, z-values, p-values are NA.

I set up the SEIR model and then solve it with the ode solver. Using that model output and the observed data, I calculate a negative log likelihood, which I then submit to the mle2 function.
When I first set it up, there were multiple errors that stopped the script from running, but now that those are resolved, I cannot seem to find the root of why the fitting doesn't work.
I am certain that the boundaries I set for the parameter estimation are sensible. The parameters are transition rates between compartments and are therefore defined as (for example) delta = 1/duration of infectiousness, so there are very real biological boundaries on what the parameters can be.

I am aware that I am trying to fit a lot of parameters with not that much data, but the same problem persists when I try only fitting one, so that cannot be the root of it.

```
library(deSolve)
library(bbmle)


#data

gdta <- c(0, 36.2708172419082, 1.57129615346629, 28.1146409459558, 147.701669719614, 311.876708482584, 512.401145459178, 563.798275104372, 470.731269976821, 292.716043742125, 153.604156195608, 125.760068922451, 198.755685044427, 143.847282793854, 69.2693867232681, 42.2093135487066, 17.0200426587424)


#build seir function
seir <- function(time, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {

    dS0 <- - beta0 * S0 * (I/N) 
    dS1 <- - beta1 * S1 * (I/N) 
    dE <- beta0 * S0 * (I/N) + beta1 * S1 * (I/N) - delta * E
    dI <- delta * E - gamma * I
    dR <- gamma * I

    return(list(c(dS0, dS1, dE, dI, dR)))
  })
}


# build function to run seir, include ode solver
run_seir <- function(time, state, beta0, beta1, delta, gamma, sigma, N, startInf) {
  parameters <- c(beta0, beta1, delta, gamma) 
  names(parameters) <- c("beta0", "beta1", "delta", "gamma")
  init <- c(S0 = (N - startInf)*(sigma) ,
            S1 = (N - startInf) * (1-sigma), 
            E = 0,
            I = startInf,
            R = 0)
  state_est <- as.data.frame(ode(y = init, times = times, func = seir, parms = parameters))
  return(state_est)
}


times <- seq(0, 16, by = 1)  #sequence  
states <- c("S0", "S1", "E", "I", "R")


# run the run_seir function to see if it works
run_seir(time = times, state= states, beta0 = 1/(1.9/7), beta1 = 0.3*(1/(1.9/7)), delta = 1/(4.1/7), gamma = 1/(4.68/7), sigma = 0.7, N = 1114100, startInf = 100)


#build calc likelihood function
calc_likelihood <- function(times, state, beta0, beta1, delta, gamma, sigma, N, startInf, CFR)  {
  model.output <- run_seir(time, state, beta0, beta1, delta, gamma, sigma, N, startInf)  
  LL <- sum(dpois(round(as.numeric(gdta)), (model.output$I)/(1/delta)*CFR, log = TRUE))
  print(LL)
  return(LL)
}


# run calc_likelihood function
calc_likelihood(time = times, state = states, beta0 = 1/(1.9/7), beta1 = 0.3*(1/(1.9/7)), delta = 1/(4.1/7), gamma = 1/(4.68/7), sigma = 0.7, N = 1114100, startInf = 100, CFR = 0.02)



#MLE

#parameters that are supposed to be fixed
fixed.pars <- c(N=1114100, startInf=100, CFR = 0.02)

#parameters that mle2 is supposed to estimate
free.pars <- c(beta0 = 1/(1.9/7), beta1 = 0.3*(1/(1.9/7)),
           delta = 1/(4.1/7), gamma = 1/(4.68/7), sigma = 0.7)



#lower bound
lower_v <- c(beta0 = 0, beta1 = 0, delta = 0, gamma = 0, sigma = 0) 
#upper bound
upper_v <- c(beta0 = 15, beta1 = 15, delta = 15, gamma = 15, sigma = 1)
#sigma = 1, this is not a typo


#mle function - need to use L-BFGS-B since we need to include boundaries
test2 <- mle2(calc_likelihood, start = as.list(free.pars), fixed = as.list(fixed.pars),method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = lower_v, upper = upper_v)

summary(test2)
```

After I run mle2, I get a warning saying:
Warning message:
In mle2(calc_likelihood, start = as.list(free.pars), fixed = as.list(fixed.pars),  :
  some parameters are on the boundary: variance-covariance calculations based on Hessian may be unreliable

and if I look at summary(test2):
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(object@vcov)) : NaNs produced

Based on the research I've done so far, I understand that the second error might be due to the estimates being on the boundaries, so my question really is how to address the first one.
If I run mle2 with only lower boundaries, I get parameter estimates in the millions, which cannot be correct.

I am fairly certain that my model specification for the SEIR is correct, but after staring at this code and trying to resolve this issue for a week, I'm open to any input on how to make the fitting work.

Thanks,
JJ